# Connecting to end user's SQL Express during installation

Tags: installation, sql-server-express

I have been writing SQL Compact C# winforms applications for a while now, with the help from all the wizards in Visual Studio. The database is created during development, and installed as-is. Then suddenly, I realise I actually have no clue how to connect to SQL Express on client's machine and install a database if I had to.

There are many examples on connection string and creating database in SQL Express via code (C# in my case) but I don't think that is what I am looking for.

If I develop an application that requires SQL Express. I know there's a feature in Visual Studio that detects and install SQL Express if it does not exist. However, how do I set up and install my database in SQL Express? Do I need to somehow get credentials somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You mention both SQL Server Compact Edition and SQL Server Express Edition; these are two different things, but for the case you've described you probably mean SQL Server Compact Edition.

SQL Server CE comes with the .Net Framework, so no install should be required. However, you will have to create a database. You can do that with [SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceengine.createdatabase%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

**EDIT**

For SQL Server Express... to get a connection string from the user without them having to actually type in a connection string, you can use a data connection dialog: [archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Connection)

Comment: Sorry for confusing. No mistake, I know SQLCE and SQL Express are different. Please read my post as-is again. I am asking about Express edition.

Comment: I edited the answer to add some info about SQL Server Express, @Jake.